# 2 column article with tall figure (revtex-4) badly placed

Tags: floats, two-column, revtex

I have a two column article. In one page I have the left column full, in the right column I've got nothing. In the next page I have a tall figure on the left column, and text, and the right column full. If there is enough space in the right column of the first page, why isn't the tall figure there?

[image]

[image]

Here there is the latex source from the first normal figure up to the paragraph that goes after the tall figure:

```
 \begin{figure}[h]
     \includegraphics[trim = 0cm 0cm 0cm 1.0cm, clip=True,width=\columnwidth]{deuterio-wolframio_40ms_30avg.pdf}
     \caption{Se muestran los espectros individuales del deuterio y del tungsteno, el espectro de la fuentes de deuterio y tungsteno encendidas al tiempo, y la de la suma de los espectros individuales del deuterio y del tungsteno. El tiempo de exposición fue de 40\si{\milli\second} y se promediaron 30 medidas.}
     \label{fig:d2w}
 \end{figure}

 Se midió también el espectro del deuterio obtenido individualmente con la fuente BDS100, así como el espectro de las fuentes de deuterio y tungsteno prendidas simultáneamente. Los espectros se muestran en la figura \ref{fig:d2w}.\\

  \begin{figure}[H]
 \captionsetup[subfigure]{font=scriptsize,labelfont=scriptsize}
\begin{center}
\subcaptionbox{Argón, tomado con tiempo de exposición de 30\si{\milli\second}.}{%
  \includegraphics[trim = 0cm 0cm 0cm 1.5cm, clip=True,width=0.8\columnwidth]{morado_30ms_30avg.pdf}%
  }\par\medskip
 \subcaptionbox{Helio, tomado con tiempo de exposición de 12 \si{\milli\second}.}{%
  \includegraphics[trim = 0cm 0cm 0cm 1.5cm, clip=True,width=0.8\columnwidth]{naranja_12ms_30avg.pdf}%
  }\par\medskip
\subcaptionbox{Oxígeno, tomado con tiempo de exposición de 150 \si{\milli\second}.\label{fig:oxigen}}{%
  \includegraphics[trim = 0cm 0cm 0cm 1.5cm, clip=True,width=0.8\columnwidth]{blanco_150ms_30avg.pdf}%
  }
\caption{Espectros de lámparas de argón, helio y oxígeno. En cada figura se muestran las líneas más importantes reportadas por el NIST \cit{nist}. Todos los espectros mostrados resultan del promedio de 30 medidas.}
\label{fig:nist}
\end{center}
\end{figure}


 De la figura \ref{fig:d2w} es importante notar que la línea morada (deuterio + tungsteno) representa intensidades siempre mayores al espectro de deuterio y tungsteno. Es decir que entre mayor sea la potencia incidente sobre el CCD menor es su sensibilidad. Este es un resultado común \cit{saturation} debido a que la diferencia de potencial que deben superar los electrones desprendidos del material fotosensible en el CCD para ser contados es cada vez mayor a medida que se acerca el punto de saturación absoluta para cada pixel.\\
```

Comment: Real quick: You appear to be terminating several paragraphs with double-backslash directives. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The right hand of page 4 column is not empty, it has the final line of the paragraph that starts

```
Se midió también el espectro
```

You can not see the final line as it is all white . TeX would have warned that this line was "underfull" (badness 10000, which is the maximum badness that it ever assigns). If you put `\\` at the end of a paragraph it *always* forces such a spurious line which looks a bit like vertical space but is a horizontal, but empty, box, and as such it is not discarded at a page break.

Here, as the following object is a large figure, it causes a whole new page to be generated, normally it causes spurious "space" at the top of the page.

Never use `\\` at the end of a paragraph, and almost never use it at all other than for ending rows in `tabular` and similar alignment environments.

The particular offending `\\` here is:

```
Los espectros se muestran en la figura \ref{fig:d2w}.\\
```